# Aggregate Results According to Another Column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), EXTRACT(year from DAY_DATE) FROM
( INNER_SELECT_QUERY )
GROUP BY DAY_DATE;
```

which returns results as like that:

```
4630    2013
7348    2014
9408    2013
5953    2013
7261    2015
5767    2013
9218    2013
14989   2013
11277   2013
```

How can I get result aggregated by distinct years? i.e.

```
22324   2015
34242   2014
23242   2013
54353   2012
```

I mean not repeated years, all related results to years are sum up?

Comment: Do the EXTRACT(year from DAY_DATE) in the "inner select", or perhaps just GROUP BY EXTRACT(year from DAY_DATE).

Comment: It is a long query to test. So, is it OK to use `EXTRACT(year from DAY_DATE)` at outer SQL as like @Gordon Linoff answered?

Comment: It's Ok with many dbms products, but not with the ANSI SQL standard.

Comment: @Kamaci: Yes it is. You are grouping by `DAY_DATE` which makes no sense, as you don't want a result record per day. You must group by `EXTRACT(year from DAY_DATE)` instead, just as Gordon suggests.

Comment: @jarlh: Why not? AFAIK `EXTRACT` is part of the standard as of SQL99. And being able to group by an expression should also be standard. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, SQL99 doesn't include group by expression. (And I don't think later versions do either.) Collate clause is however fine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `extract()` on in the `group by`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), EXTRACT(year from DAY_DATE)
FROM ( INNER_SELECT_QUERY )
GROUP BY EXTRACT(year from DAY_DATE) ;
```